# I was trying to write a letter repetition counting function but it is not working

Tags: python

The function is supposed to take a string like:

```
'kkikkd'
```

and return a list of the letters and their repetitive values i.e.

```
[[k,2],[i,1],[k,2],[d,1]]
```

but it isn't working. Any ideas?

```
def chnum(xtrr):
    lis2 = []
    for n in xtrr:
         if lis2[0][0] == n:
               continue
    lis1 = [n]
    for m in xtrr:
         if n == m:
               i += 1
         lis1 += [i]
         lis2 += [lis1]
    return lis2
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. It makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @kgemp, welcome on stackoverflow :) In order to help you, we need to see your code and your attempts to solve your problem. If you are unsure, how to ask a good question, help is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have got your question correctly then you are trying to keep count of each character in a string and store the result in a list. The brute force way of doing is using a dictionary to keep track of character and number of times it has appeared.
Here is the code:

```
 st= "kkikkd"
 l=[]
 temp=1
 for i in range(1,len(st)):
    if st[i-1] == st[i]:
        temp += 1
    else:
        l.append([st[i-1],temp])
        temp= 1
if st[i] == st[i-1]:
    temp += 1
l.append([st[i],temp])
```

output: [['k', 2], ['i', 1], ['k', 2], ['d', 1]]

Comment: If you set `string = "kkikkd"`in your answer code and run it, you will notice that it does not produce the required result.

Comment: @jpeg I think I didn't get the question correctly could you please explain the question?

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain the question better, it has actually been clearly asked: the OP seeks `[[k,2],[i,1],[k,2],[d,1]]` as a result for `'kkikkd'`, i.e. counting consecutive repetitions of a letter in the string, not the overall count of a letter in the string.

Comment: @jpeg thanks I got it. Kindly check the new code that I have just edited and tell me if something is not correct.

Comment: You're welcome. Your code seems to produce the required answer now. Still, I would recommend to use the original example in your answer code: `st= "kkikkd"`. That helps the OP and anyone else testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = 'kkikkd' 
>>> [[k, len(list(v))] for k,v in groupby(s)]
[['k', 2], ['i', 1], ['k', 2], ['d', 1]]
```

Alternatively you can also use `re.findall` to do this

```
>>> import re
>>> [[k, len(v)] for v,k in re.findall(r'((.)\2*)', s)]
[['k', 2], ['i', 1], ['k', 2], ['d', 1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

To begin with, there are 2 problems in your code

```
def chnum(xtrr):
    lis2 = []
    for n in xtrr:
        if lis2[0][0] == n:  # lis2 is empty. It does not have 0th element, much less another nested list.
        # this will only check if n is in the first element of lis2, what about all the other elements?
            continue
        lis1=[n]
        i = 0
        for m in xtrr:
            if n== m:
                i+=1
        lis1 += [i]
        lis2 += [lis1]
     return lis2
print(chnum('kkidduus'))
```

But instead of fixing it I would advise to use the power of python. In particular its dictionaries
like so:

```
def chnum(xtrr):
    d = {n:0 for n in xtrr}  # create a dict where keys are letters from input string
    for n in xtrr:
        d[n] += 1
        # for each letter from input increment the dict's value for that letter
    return d

print(chnum('kkidduus'))
```

You will see how much more concise and readable this code is.
if you are really adamant about getting results as nested lists then this dictionary is also a good starting point. Just do`l = [list(t) for t in chnum('kkidduus').items()]` afterwards

EDIT:
the OP wants to see counts at every repetition of the letter, so the code above can be modified to accomodate that

```
def chnum(xtrr):
    d = {n:0 for n in xtrr}  # create a dict where keys are letters from input string
    for n in xtrr:
        d[n] += 1
        # for each letter from input increment the dict's value for that letter
    l = [[n, d[n]] for n in xtrr]
    return l

print(chnum('kkidduus'))
```

using a dictionary still has merit here as dict keys are hashed and thus will have speed advantages when counting letter occurence

Comment: If you run `print(chnum('kkikkd'))` with your answer code, you will notice that it does not produce the required result.

Comment: Thanks it works but here's the problem if you input the string 'kkikkd' it returns {'k':4, 'i':1, 'd':1} when it is supposed to return {'k':2, 'i':1, 'k':2, 'd':1} , and I am trying not to use libraries.

Comment: @kgemp no libraries are used in my answer apart from the Standard Library